# Django template inheritance

Tags: django, django-templates

I've 2 templates. Here is the listing:
1)base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    {% load staticfiles %}
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href={% static 'resume/stylesheet.css'%}/>
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id=header> some info </div>
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

2)person.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Personal info{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div>{{person.first_name}}</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I use template "person.html" in my view

```
def person_view(request):
    person = get_object_or_404(Person, pk=1)
    return render(request, "resume/person.html", {'person': person})
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^$', views.person_view, name='person'),
```

The problem is, when I run the server, and trying to open page with this url, there is only text and information from "person.html" template(meaning of "person.first_name"). Information from "base.html" and css styles don't used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot double quotes:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href={% static 'resume/stylesheet.css'%}/>
```

should be:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'resume/stylesheet.css'%}"/>
```

**Edit**

here as well:

```
<div id=header>
```

should be:

```
<div id="header">
```

Comment: Didnt help. Morover line "some info" from "base.html" didnt shown on result page. But if i add line <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'resume/stylesheet.css'%}"/> with or without quotes in "person.html" css styles work.

Comment: Thanks for help, but still the same result(

Comment: Ok, if styles work, that means template inheritance works fine. Problem is somewhere in browser rendering html. Look at page source in browser, do you see expected html, or it's missing from there too?

Comment: styles work only if I add row with link to css styles in "person.html", text from div with id "header" missing too.

Comment: do you have more than one base.html?  Django might be finding the wrong one first